# BFS on 2D grid with traceable path

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, breadth-first-search

the problem may be familiar, but with a little twist. I have a grid (2D array) with possible markings:
"?" - unexplored
"." - walkable
"#" - wall
"G" - goal

Every time I walk in certain direction (no diagonals), I discover 5x5 area around me. Ater I discover "G", I have to find the shortest path to the starting point.

So I am trying BFS for both scenarios. It seems to work on simple paths with one direction like:

```
????####
????..S#
????####
????????
????????
```

where the map looks like:

```
 ########
 #.....S#
 #.######
 #......#
 ########
```

But sometimes it gets stuck when there are many possibilities for me to go. It finds "closest" (not really sure about that) "?" symbol, returns path and I go to the first coordinate and BFS from this point again. But I sometimes get stuck when I go in that direction, BFS, and algorithm finds "closer" "?" in opposite direction, then I go back and forth.

I think something is wrong with my algorithm, because paths returned for e.g. left/right differ with like 3-4 nodes.

```
function BFS(position,map,checked,target,avoid){
    var Q = [[new Node(position.x,position.y)]];
    var Path;
    d=0;
    while(Q.length >0){
        Path = Q.shift();
        vertex = Path[Path.length-1];

        if(Map[vertex.y][vertex.x] == target){
            return Path;
        }

        else if(checked[vertex.y][vertex.x] == 0){

            if(vertex.x+1<C && Map[vertex.y][vertex.x+1] !="#" && checked[vertex.y][vertex.x+1] == 0){
                new_path = Path.slice();
                new_path.push(new Node(vertex.x+1,vertex.y));
                Q.unshift(new_path);
            }
            if(vertex.x+1<C && Map[vertex.y][vertex.x+1] == "G"){
                G_discovered = true;
                G_position = new Node(vertex.x+1, vertex.y);
            } 


            if(vertex.y+1<R && Map[vertex.y+1][vertex.x] !="#" && checked[vertex.y+1][vertex.x] == 0){
                new_path = Path.slice();
                new_path.push(new Node(vertex.x,vertex.y+1));
                Q.unshift(new_path);
            }
            if(vertex.y+1<R && Map[vertex.y+1][vertex.x] == "G"){
                G_discovered = true;
                G_position = new Node(vertex.x, vertex.y+1);
            } 



            if(vertex.x-1>=0 && Map[vertex.y][vertex.x-1] !="#" && checked[vertex.y][vertex.x-1] == 0){
                new_path = Path.slice();
                new_path.push(new Node(vertex.x-1,vertex.y));
                Q.unshift(new_path);
            }
            if(vertex.x-1>=0 && Map[vertex.y][vertex.x-1] == "G" ){
                G_discovered = true;
                G_position = new Node(vertex.x-1, vertex.y);
            } 

            if(vertex.y-1>=0 && Map[vertex.y-1][vertex.x] !="#" && checked[vertex.y-1][vertex.x] == 0){
                new_path = Path.slice();
                new_path.push(new Node(vertex.x,vertex.y-1));
                Q.unshift(new_path);
            }
            if(vertex.y-1>=0 && Map[vertex.y-1][vertex.x] == "G"){
                G_discovered = true;
                G_position = new Node(vertex.x, vertex.y-1);
            }
            d++;
            checked[vertex.y][vertex.x] = 1;
        }
    }
    return "no path found"
}
```

Every move I read map in the Map object and every move I clear the checked array

Comment: Is the parameter `map` passed to the function the same as `Map`?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. It updates before every move (every BFS call)

Comment: Could you please describe the term "scenario" a little more?

Comment: If you mean the goal or what I have to do, is as follows: As a starting input, I get size of map and how many moves I have to get from goal to start. Every game turn you get the map with "?","#" and so on. At first you do not know where the "G" is, so you have to explore the map. For that I try to BFS to closest "?" avoiding "G". When I find "G", I am supposed to check if distance from "G" to start is <= given number of moves (starting input). If not, there is shorter path through unexplored map part, so I continue to explore map until there are no "?". For all 3 searches I use BFS

Comment: I think the problem could lie in the fact that shift takes elements from the beginning and unshift adds them to the beginning. So you basically have a LIFO behavior (DFS) instead of a FIFO.

Comment: Couldn't you simply explore the whole map and then compute the shortest path?

Comment: Thank you, @AdrianJałoszewski, changing `unshift` to `push` seems to have solved the issue

Comment: I forgot to mention, @piotrekg2, that I have only 1200 moves combined. Should be enough to explore map, but don't want to be short on moves while travelling back